# Highlighting multiple lines

Tags: jekyll, pygments

I am using pygments for syntax highlighting and want to highlight some lines in the code. This works fine for highlighting one line but how would I highlight multiple lines? 
I have tried comma and space seperated lists to no avail.

```
{% highlight python hl_lines=7 %} # works
{% highlight python hl_lines=7,8 %} # does not work
{% highlight python hl_lines=7 8 %} # does not work
{% highlight python hl_lines=7-8 %} # does not work
```

Comment: It looks like someone else is having this problem and had to solve it with a patch: http://www.madhur.co.in/blog/2012/03/05/codehighlightjekyll.html. I'm not able to test this on my machine but it might be a good place to start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a string and separate the line numbers by a space.

```
{% highlight python linenos hl_lines="1 3 4" %}
def say_hi(to_who):
    print "Hello,", to_who

say_hi("World")
{% endhighlight %}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with using just a `{% highlight %}` tag by itself. I always use it in combination with `{% endhighlight %}` to identify code blocks. This works as expected on my Jekyll 0.12.1 install.

```
{% highlight python %}

def say_hi(to_who):
    print "Hello,", to_who

say_hi("World")

{% endhighlight %}
```

With the default CSS in place (and tweaked a little for the background color), the above produces this:

[image: Example of Pygments output]

Comment: The end tag is there just removed from question, I think you are confusing syntax highlighting with line highlighting.

Comment: Apologies, I didn't properly understand the question. I'll leave the answer here though so other folks don't make the same mistake. I also added a comment to the main question that points to another post where someone else is having the same issue. Makes it look like the problem is actually a bug that needs to be patched.